# Call a mobile number from iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

I need my iOS app to make a call using a phone number.

The call should get connected by SIM network and not via the internet/data.

If anyone has any idea on how this can be achieved, kindly guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to open Telephone application and make a call with a given number.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", @"Your phone number here"]]];
```

Comment: @ tyt_g207: As per your answer it will open by default Iphone Calling screen buddy. but i don't want to open that one .do we have any alternative way to make call by sim network from our IOS App so that we can customize calling screen as per our requirement.

Comment: I think that there is no way to do that. Even you can find one (maybe by private API), Apple will reject applications that make a call themselves (without passed by Telephone).

Comment: hey As per your link it will be one library i think so right.it will not connect the call by mobile sim network...right

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the private API [TelephonyUI.framework](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS8-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework). That's the solution to your requirement.